# Add text to a picture using photoshop

Tags: templates, photo, photoshop, image

I want to know if exist templates to add text on photoshop like in the following pictures:
http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/485070_566956359990277_263279122_n.jpg

https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/3263_403189956409783_609225582_n.jpg

Could you suggest some pages where I can study and try those effects ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Find the fonts. Search on font sites for similiar fonts or try to cut out the font and upload it to http://www.whatfontis.com/ or http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Step2: just play around with blending options and stuff.

from what I can see it's these settings you want too look at:

- "Notche Latina": Gradient overlay, white stroke and black dropshadow.
- "photo recoblablabla": inner shadow and might be in overlay-mode or something
- "Festival de la bira": once again, white stroke

Answer (score 0):

First make a layer adjust the objcet on layer as per your requirement.
Add some effects from filter gallery if you required (or layer style).

Click on the text toolbar type your text (required text).Then to apply effects 
right click on text layer and click on rasterize type.now you can add effects from the filter gallery to the text.(or Layer style eg-inner shadows,bevel and emboss).